# Grouping sets by year, month, and date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, grouping-sets

Is it possible to rollup the date, month, and year using `GROUPING SETS`, where the dates are shownn and grouped into month, and year, and the value for month and year are displayed instead of being `null`?

Here is the sample data, and my attempt at using grouping sets

```
create table #tbl_data
(
employeeId int
,productLine int
,salesDate datetime
,salesTotal money
)

insert into #tbl_data
values
(1,1,'02/09/2017',199)
,(1,1,'04/10/2017',379)
,(2,1,'04/21/2017',323)
,(2,1,'04/10/2017',461)
,(2,1,'06/11/2017',304)
,(3,1,'01/28/2017',147)
,(3,1,'02/09/2017',320)
,(4,1,'03/07/2017',344)
,(4,1,'03/13/2017',176)

select
    productLine, 
    employeeId, 
    salesDate, 
    mon=month(salesdate),
    yr=year(salesdate), 
    sum(salesTotal) as salesTotal
from 
    #tbl_data

group by grouping sets
(
    (productLine, employeeId, salesDate)
    ,(productLine, employeeId)
    ,(productLine)
)
```

Here is what returned by the query (left) and what i wanted to accomplish (right)

[image]

Comment: try group by with cube or rollup

Comment: @RenatoAfonso, can you suggest something more specific? I tried cube and rollup - without success - before asking the question here.

Comment: select
    productLine, 
    employeeId, 
    salesDate, 
    mon=month(salesdate),
    yr=year(salesdate), 
    sum(salesTotal) as salesTotal
from 
    #tbl_data

group by cube (productline, employeeid, salesdate,mon,yr)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use:

```
;WITH cte AS (
  select
    productLine, 
    employeeId, 
    salesDate, 
    mon=month(salesdate),
    yr=year(salesdate),
    salesTotal
  from #tbl_data   
)
select
    productLine, 
    employeeId, 
    salesDate, 
    mon,
    yr ,
    sum(salesTotal) as salesTotal
from cte
group by grouping sets
(
     (productLine, employeeId, salesDate, yr)
    ,(productLine, employeeId, yr)
    ,(productLine)
    ,(productLine, mon, yr)
);
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/FQFNE16951)**

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Iad2025! It's very close. How do you group the saledates in the same month for an employee under the month? Please refer to my screenshot where the big arrows in red are pointing at.

Comment: I got it. Just simply add ,(productLine, employeeId, mon) the grouping sets